# Using Bootstrap Datepicker in the created table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm creating a data grip for a project and I need to use Bootstrap Datepicker to the Date field.
The problem is that in the table only the first row (that is previously created) has the datepicker working.
If I create a second row, the datepicker isn't working.

Could you please help me? I would like to have the datepicker working fine in every created row and only on the Date field.

Below is my code:

```js
function getElementsByClassName(c,el){
    if(typeof el=='string'){
        el=document.getElementById(el);
    }
    if(!el){
        el=document;
    }
    if(el.getElementsByClassName){
        return el.getElementsByClassName(c);
    }
    var arr=[],
        allEls=el.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;i<allEls.length;i++){
        if(allEls[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(c)>-1){arr.push(allEls[i])}
    }
    return arr;
}

function killMe(el){
    return el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

function getParentByTagName(el,tag){
    tag=tag.toLowerCase();
    while(el.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=tag){
        el=el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}

// Delete table row
function delRow(){
        killMe(getParentByTagName(this,'tr'));
}

// Insert table row
function addRow() {
    var table = getParentByTagName(this,'table')
    var lastInputs=table.rows.length>2?
        table.rows[table.rows.length-2].getElementsByTagName('input'):[];
    for(var i=0;i<lastInputs.length-1;i++){
        if(lastInputs[i].value==''){return false;}
    }

    // New table row vars
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);
    

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.id = "expenseDate";
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.className="form-control datepicker";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.className="form-control";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.className="form-control";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.className="form-control";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);
    

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "button";
    element5.className="del btn btn-sm btn-danger";
    element5.value='X';
    element5.onclick=delRow;
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

}
```

```css
#ExpensesTable {
 margin-top: 30px;
}

#ExpensesTable tr {
 margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#ExpensesTable td {
 padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
}
#ExpensesTable th {
 padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
 </head> 
 <body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <div class="container">
 
  <table id="ExpensesTable">
      <tr>
          <th>Date:</th>
          <th>From:</th>
          <th>To:</th>
          <th>Nr. Km:</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><input class="add btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button" value="Add expense" id="AddExpense"/></td>
      </tr>
  </table>

 </div>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
      var els=getElementsByClassName("add","ExpensesTable");
      for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
          els[i].onclick=addRow;
      }
      els[0].onclick();
      })();
  </script>
  <script>
   $('#expenseDate').datepicker({
   });
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The original version: http://jsfiddle.net/9gnAx/

Comment: I think the problem is related with the way I'm calling the datepicker in the HTML... But I can't reach anything...

Comment: hi @Hugo, take a look at code I posted,, I think that's what will help you get started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to leverage jquery to speed coding up and then you end up with like,, 4-5 lines of code to do what you need :)

cheers,

```js
$('.dateP').datetimepicker();

$('.dupli').on( 'click', function(e){
  var dup = $('.cpy').first().clone();
  $('.table').append( dup );
  $('.dateP').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Event name</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dupli">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cpy">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="e1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='input-group dateP'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please add a button in the last column of each line to delete that line?

Comment: Another problem is that i'm trying to add this to a dynaform in ProcessMaker. The problem is that in ProcessMaker (and I imported everything well) the Datepicker only works for the first row...

Comment: I resolved the issue that you originally asked for, and if you need more help please ask another question,, if my answer helped you it would be nice to click little "UP" arrow and checkmark :)

Comment: Can you please help me in another question? It's the same code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151566/jquery-math-operations-for-my-datagrid