# JQuery math operations for my DataGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, datagrid

I have the following data grid:

```js
$('.dateP').datetimepicker();

$('.dupli').on( 'click', function(e){
  var dup = $('.cpy').first().clone();
  $('.table').append( dup );
  $('.dateP').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>Price per Km: 0,36</p>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Km Nr:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dupli">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cpy">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="e1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='input-group dateP'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<p>Total expenses: (sum of row values)</p>
```

I would like to have in jQuery a method to count the number of rows (created by the user) then make the multiplication for each row (nr Km * Price per KM) and give me the final value that is the sum of all rows values.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did update for you,, see if that's ok for your needs,

cheers

update: Hugo, you are very demanding.. I almost developed full web app here and you didn't even buy me a beer man :)

```js
var frmt = {format: 'DD/MM/YYYY', viewMode: 'days'};
$('.dateP').datetimepicker( frmt );
// duplicate the row
$('.dupli').on( 'click', function(e){
  if( $('.cpy').last().find('input').first().val() != ''
    && $('.cpy').last().find('input').last().val() != '' ){    
      var dup = $('.cpy').first().clone();
      $('.table').append( dup );
      $('.dateP').datetimepicker( frmt );
      calc(); // on creation of new row do the calc
  }
});
// remove the row
$(document).on( 'click', '.remove', function(el){ 
  if( $('.cpy').length > 1 ){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); calc();
  }
});
// function for calc
function calc(){
  var kp = $('.price').val(); // price
  var sum = 0;
  $('.km').each( function(ix){
    sum += $(this).val() * kp;
  });
  $('.fin').val( sum );
}
// on input update the total
$(document).on( 'change input', '.km', calc );
$('.price').on( 'change input', calc );
```

```css
.remove{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="form-inline col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  Price per Km: <input type='number' class="form-control price" value="0.36" step="0.01" min="0.2" max="5" /></div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Km Nr:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dupli">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cpy">
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control km" >
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='input-group dateP'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <i class="fa fa-trash remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p class="form-inline">Total expenses: <input type='number' class="form-control fin" /></p>
```

Comment: Could you please also add a method to remove lines?

Comment: In each row add one more column with some kind of trash button. When you click on that button, that line is removed and the total is updated too.

Comment: I added that trash button, take a look

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's nice! Can I just ask you one more thing? All the fields must be mandatory. In this case should not be possible to create another line if the previous line was not correctly filled.

Comment: here you go @HugoFigueira

Comment: How can i remove the timestamp from the datepicker? I just need the day/month/year.

Comment: Kresimir Pendic could you please give me a help using this in ProcessMaker? Do you know what is this tool?

Comment: If you want you can give me a contact (email for example). I can pay you some beers :)

Comment: hey @HugoFigueira you don't have to, here on SO it's cool to click UP arrow or accept answer,, but if you insist you can go to my profile and click codementor link :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this fiddle i made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/kks3bL06/

i have added a class to the kilometer input. go with foreach over all the kilometer fields, add the sum and write it into the span.

```js
$('.dateP').datetimepicker();

$('.dupli').on( 'click', function(e){
  var dup = $('.cpy').first().clone();
  $('.table').append( dup );
  $('.dateP').datetimepicker();
});


$('.kilometer').change(function() {
var total = 0;
 $('.kilometer').each(function(index,obj){
          total += $(obj).val() * 0.36;
 });
 $('.total').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<p>Price per Km: 0,36</p>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Km Nr:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dupli">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cpy">
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control kilometer" id="e1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class='input-group dateP'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
Total expeses: 
<span class="total"></span>
</div>
```